# how to click on a button in the iphone application and link to a website

Tags: iphone

i am developing a iphone application in a view-based project,(not navigation) however i would like to click on a button in that application and able to link to a website,anyone can give me some hint how to make the view being transistion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [This question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30058/how-can-i-launch-the-google-maps-iphone-application-from-within-my-own-native-a).  Short version:

```
[someUIApplication openURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString: @"http://www.yahoo.com"]]
```