# How to link to Google Map directions from iPhone app

Tags: cocoa-touch

I have been developing a location based application and would ideally like to link directly to the directions using the Google application.

I have seen a few applications such as AroundMe which already seem to do this but I can't work out how they have managed to implement it

Comment: Seems this has already been asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30058/how-can-i-launch-the-google-maps-iphone-application-from-within-my-own-native-app

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The question was about opening maps with the navigation directions displayed, not just the map. The iPhone's URL scheme supports a source & destination address - try, for example:

```
NSString* urlString = @"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=London+UK&daddr=Birmingham+UK";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: urlString]];
```

Comment: Thanks this looks like what, I need, sorry for missing that other post I had searched first. Just need to get it to take co-ords now, but should be able to crack that from googlemaps itself

Comment: FYI you can just put "51.234231,-1.231232" in the saddr and daddr string if you need co-ord based lookups

Answer (score 0):

Use OpenURL to start google maps with the correct location, just like described in [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30058/how-can-i-launch-the-google-maps-iphone-application-from-within-my-own-native-a).

Extract from there: Use

```
[someUIApplication openURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?g=London"]]
```

instead of `g=London` you can also use more for the URL format to drop pins, or move to a GPS location (possibly the current location you previously got from your application by asking core location)

Unrelated:

Please comment if somebody has a suggestion on how to handle duplicate and or/related questions on stack overflow. I'm still new around here :-)