# On the iphone, how do I add a location to the maps application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mkmapview

Is there a way to add a location from an MKMapView in my application to the built-in Google Maps app?

From what I understand there is probably one of two ways to do it: using [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:xxx] (like opening a web address, writing an email, or dialling a number) or using a C-api like adding a contact to the address book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30058/how-can-i-launch-the-google-maps-iphone-application-from-within-my-own-native-app) may have just the answer you're looking for, or maybe I misunderstood the question.

If you're not a link clicker:

```
[someUIApplication openURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?g=London"]]
```

Comment: I think the poster means "Add the bookmark without actually leaving the application."

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately. I assume you mean add it as a bookmark of course, given that recents and contacts are more 'dynamic' lists.