# jQuery and iPhone native app development

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, objective-c

How to use [JqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/) (javascript ) charting libraries in a native application for iphone?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the UIWebView component. Then you can develop the app or just a piece of it like you would for a web app.

See the answer to this question:

[Native iPhone app in HTML/Javascript ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054333/native-iphone-app-in-html-javascript)