# Drop Pin on Default Google Map from My App. How?

Tags: iphone, google-maps, mkmapview

I am new to iphone development. In my application, I have address for a location in group table cell, when i click the address text in group table cell. The pin should be dropped in default  google map app to the corresponding address. is there any in-built functionality available for that?.Any Idea??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question is answered by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30058/how-can-i-launch-the-google-maps-iphone-application-from-within-my-own-native-app).