# Display an address on a map on the iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit

If I supply an address as a NSString. How can I use mapkit to show me a map with that location centered and a push pin showing that address? What's the easiest way to do this?

EDIT:
Is there a way to call the built-in Maps app to do that for me?

Comment: To answer your edit, **yes.**  You can call the built in Maps app, but it requires switching away from your application.  See this SO question for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30058/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to [forward geocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocoding) the address to obtain GPS coordinates.  This data is available from third parties like Google via their [Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/).  Here's a [tutorial on forward geocoding using Google APIs](http://blog.sallarp.com/ipad-iphone-forward-geocoding-api-google/).

Take note of their [terms of use](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits).

Comment: does it allow commercial use? if the end-user makes the request then the limit wouldn't be an issue right?

Comment: It's probably fine for your purposes, but apps with very high query volumes or a lack of Google Maps UI could get blocked.