# Bing Maps Launcher

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm aware of the Map control, but I would like to open bing maps app instead. Is there a way ? Otherwise, I'll do a Page that displays a Map control fullscreen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Is there a way to open the Bing Maps App on Windows Phone 7 to a specific location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358232/is-there-a-way-to-open-the-bing-maps-app-on-windows-phone-7-to-a-specific-locatio)

Short answer: **no** direct way to launch the Bing maps app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Bing Maps Task, and specify the location:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394026%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

```
BingMapsTask bingMapsTask = new BingMapsTask();
bingMapsTask.Center = new GeoCoordinate(47.6204, -122.3493);
bingMapsTask.ZoomLevel = 2;

bingMapsTask.Show();
```