# send google maps link via in-app email

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

actually am developing an iOS application that allows the user to send his position via mail or sms.

I want just to send an email containing a link like http://maps.google.com/maps?q=London
 Then the receiver have just to touch that link to open maps application

Is there any way to do that
thank in advance

Comment: What is the question? Any other way of sending the link or any other way of opening the maps app?

Answer (score 1):

That's built-in to the Mail app in iOS. If you send yourself http://maps.google.com/maps?q=London in an email, and open it on an iOS device it will automatically link it to the Maps app. If you want to link to the Maps app from a different app see this link [How can I launch the Google Maps iPhone application from within my own native application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30058/how-can-i-launch-the-google-maps-iphone-application-from-within-my-own-native-ap)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like putting a hyper link inside the message body of the email, and setting the isHTML property to YES when making the message body of your MFMailComposeViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into the `MFMessageComposeViewController` and `MFMailComposeViewController` classes. `MFMessageComposeViewController` has the `body` property while `MFMailComposeViewController` has the `setMessageBody:isHTML:` method.

After you implement these modal view controller you can easily take http://maps.google.com/maps?q=London set the respective property/use the respective method to fill the message/email body with your maps link along with any other text you want to add.