# MKMapItem with specific Location

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, mkmapitem

How can I launch the default maps app for iOS6 and pass it a custom location?

For example:

```
[[MKMapItem setLocation:MyLocation] openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:nil];
```

I followed the example here, but was unable to figure it out. [How can I launch the Google Maps iPhone application from within my own native application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30058/how-can-i-launch-the-google-maps-iphone-application-from-within-my-own-native-ap/12692609#12692609)

Comment: You open MKMapItem with an specific location. You can use either the user location, or a location defined by a MKPlacemark. What is the problem you are having?

Comment: OK thanks,

i'am a newbie in xcode.

How can I set a Placemark?

for example with these Coordinates?

latitude = 51.455919; longitude = 6.746442;

thank's :)

Comment: MKPlacemark *placemark=[[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.455919, 6.746442) addressDictionary:yourLocationAddressDictionary];

Comment: ok thanks :) thas now my code: MKPlacemark *placemark=[[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.455919, 6.746442) addressDictionary:yourLocationAddressDictionary];
  
        
    [[MKMapItem setLocation:placemark]openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:nil];       but i get 2 errors 1."Use of undeclared identifier 'yourLocationAddressDictionary'"     2. "No Known class method for selector 'setLocation'"

Comment: You need to create a dictionary with the address information. Note that to create this dictionary you need to use the keys from the address book. Take a look at one dictionary I create: NSDictionary *addressDictionary=@{(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStreetKey : yourLocationStreet, (NSString *)kABPersonAddressCityKey : yourLocationCity, (NSString *)kABPersonAddressStateKey : yourLocationState, (NSString *)kABPersonAddressZIPKey : yourLocationPostalCode, (NSString *)kABPersonAddressCountryKey : yourLocationCountry};

Comment: You can also geocode the coordinate you have, and that will give you a placemark with the proper address dictionary you can use.

Comment: ok thanks, but is there no easyer way to open the Maps App at a particular location? I  also know the coordinate.

Comment: You are opening at a particular location. You are passing a location with the MKMapItem

Comment: Ok but I do not know how it works :( I'am a newbi in Xcode. Can you give me a Code which open the Maps App at 51.455919,6.746442 ? Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here is the code to open the Maps native application with a custom location:

```
double latitude = 35.0;
double longitude = 1.0;
MKPlacemark *placemark = [[[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude) addressDictionary:nil] autorelease];
MKMapItem *mapItem = [[[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark] autorelease];
[mapItem setName:@"Name of your location"];
[mapItem openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:nil];
```