# Converting latitude/longitude doubles into MKMapItems for obtaining directions

Tags: ios, core-data, mapkit, mkmapitem

I'm working on a Core Data project and early on I discovered `MKMapItems` are not `NSCoder` compliant, so I'm storing `MKMapItem`s' coordinates as doubles in core data and retrieving them later for generating directions to a destination.

I found the answer in the post below to be helpful in explaining how to generate directions, but I don't know how to go about turning my `latitude` & `longitude double`s back into a `MKMapItem`. Is this something that can be done?

[is there a way to get directions in mkmapview using a built in apple API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19772900/is-there-a-way-to-get-directions-in-mkmapview-using-a-built-in-apple-api)

Comment: do you have a problem with initing it by Placemark? because you can do it via: `–initWithPlacemark:`.

Comment: Like this?--> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692924/mkmapitem-with-specific-location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@holex pointed me in the right direction for a solution. Turning latitude/longitude coordinates from Core Data into a MKMapItem can be accomplished with the following code:

```
MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([self.destinationLatitude doubleValue], [self.destinationLongitude doubleValue]) addressDictionary:nil];
MKMapItem *destination = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];
[mapItem setName:@"Name of your location"];
```

Comment: init(coordinate:) is only available on iOS 10.0 and newer