# Loading Maps App from iOS SDK 6.1 with Target iOS 5.0

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios6, mapkit

I'd like to support iOS5 in my app which I compile with the iOS 6.1 SDK.

One functionality is to take the User to the Maps App. [Here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30058/how-can-i-launch-the-google-maps-iphone-application-from-within-my-own-native-ap/30079#30079) explaining how to do it with iOS SDK 5 for iOS 5 and also with iOS SDK 6 for iOS 6.

However, if I use iOS 6.1 SDK and use a iOS 5 device, the [magic URL link](http://handleopenurl.com/scheme/map) takes me to the maps.google.com Website in Mobile Safari, not the native Maps App, as desired.

Can this be fixed?

**EDIT**

So far, I have this:

```
BOOL appleMapsSupported = FALSE;
NSString *reqSysVer = @"6.0";
NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
if ([currSysVer compare:reqSysVer options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
    appleMapsSupported = TRUE;
if (appleMapsSupported){
    NSLog(@"device version %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]);
    MKPlacemark* placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate addressDictionary:@{(NSString*)kABPersonAddressStreetKey:@"Your Place"}];
    MKMapItem* mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];
    [mapItem openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:@{MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey : MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeWalking}];
}else{
    NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/?t=m&q=Your+Place%%40%g,%g", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple have updated their URL handling for maps, you need to point to `maps.apple.com`, which will appropriately re-direct to Google. [See the documentation for more/how](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007894-SW1).

Comment: Just replaced `maps.google.com` with `maps.apple.com` in my app and tested, but the same problem persists.

Comment: This may be a bug then, the bottom of (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/MapKit/MapKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH3-SW1) states that for iOS 5, you need to use the URL scheme. This links to the same page I did.

Comment: +1 You pointed me to the right direction. Reading the specs more thoroughly, the URL has to start with `http://maps.apple.com/?q`. (the `?q` being critical.) Now it works. :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The linked answer looks fine. All you need to do is to check which version of iOS the user is running on, via [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/check-iphone-ios-version), and execute the appropriate code for the iOS 6 case and the iOS less-than-6 case.