# Google Maps URL scheme not working on iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, ios9, url-scheme

The following URL scheme was working on previous version but doesn't work anymore on iOS 9:

```
comgooglemaps://?q=Google+Japan,+Minato,+Tokyo,+Japan&center=35.660888,139.73073&zoom=15&views=transit
```

Did something change on iOS 9 that prevent apps from opening other apps using URL schemes?

Answer (score 31):

In iOS 9, Apple has made a change to the handling of URL schemes.
Now you need to add "LSApplicationQueriesSchemes" key in plist and then add URLScheme you want to call.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
 <string>comgooglemaps</string>
</array>
```

Comment: I've added this but i still get the error message "-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "comgooglemaps://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme comgooglemaps""

Answer (score 19):

In iOS 9.0, further restrictions were placed on the `canOpenURL` method -- for this method to work, you will need to add a `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` array to your app's `info.plist` file, and then add items for each `URL scheme` you will want to query. These schemes as `comgooglemaps`, `comgooglemaps-x-callback`, and your own app's custom URL scheme.

I have added following items in my info.plist.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>comgooglemaps</string>
    <string>comgooglemaps-x-callback</string>
</array>
```

Try with this sample code [OpenInGoogleMaps-iOS](https://github.com/googlemaps/OpenInGoogleMaps-iOS).