# Check if a certain app is installed on device with React Native

Tags: react-native

From my app, I'm trying to check if another app is installed (in my example, Google Maps). So I tried to use:

```
Linking.canOpenURL('comgooglemaps://?daddr=' + address + '&directionsmode=walking').then(supported => {...}).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
```

But it returns that it's not supported so it's like Google Maps is not installed. Do you know a way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're having this problem with iOS.

Starting with iOS 9, you have to declare the URL scheme you want to use. [See this other answer with the details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32777034/158525).

Or the official doc: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start#step_7_declare_the_url_schemes_used_by_the_api